# Selenium tool for UI

Tags: selenium

I installed selenium tool in my firefox. I recorded the login details testcases in selenium and saved it, whenever i want to test the login module i used to play the recorded testcases. Its quite simple and easy.
   I want to improve the code wise testing using selenium.
Could you please help me how to perform that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

[SeleniumHQ](http://seleniumhq.org/)

[Documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/)

Please make your question a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

basic steps to begin writing selenium tests are the following:
1) start with selenium IDE in ffox  (as you mentioned in your quiestion)
2) record test
3) export your test as java/junit4/webdriver
4) set up e.g. intelij IDEA ide in the following way:
-set up maven.dont forget about environment variables 
 - open idea > project structure. select your installed JDK
 - create project > crate project from scratch
 - maven module
 - create from archetype ( tciked checkbox). 
select  maven-archetype-quickstart. press finish
 -  you've  created new project. Now add approptiate dependency  in POM.xml

```
 <dependency> <groupId>org.seleniumhq.
selenium</groupId> <artifactId>selenium-
java</artifactId> <version>2.24.1</version>
</dependency>
```

-select red underlined pieces of code. press alt+enter . maven gonna update repository indices
- now you can copy/past to the create project your recorded selenium test. it gonna be smth like that:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class HomePageTest extends SeleneseTestBase{

static WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void openFirefox(){

driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Test
public void testHomePage(){
driver.get("https://www.google.by/");
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbqfq\"]"));
search.sendKeys("laptop");
search.submit();

}

@After
public void closeFirefox(){
// driver.quit();
}

}
```

press run. enjoy)